# Using Bundle Install and Rake in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

I'm having a problem with ruby on rails. I run

```
rake db:create
```

But get told a certain gem is missing and to run

```
bundle install
```

I run this and try to rake again but get told the same gem is missing and to run bundle install again. This goes on forever.

```
Could not find slop-3.6.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: If you've updated spring recently, remember to run `spring binstub`

Comment: Post the full error message please.

Comment: did you add the gem to your Gemfile before running bundle install?

Comment: run `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: Added. But once again running bundle install does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundler to run `rake`

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Comment: Please add your Gemfile's contents and the output of both `bundle install` and `bundle exec rake db:create`